# How do you quickly compile and run in BlueJ?

Tags: java, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, bluej

I've used IntelliJ and VSC before, both of which had nice one-button solutions to compile and run, even going as far as having keyboard shortcuts for it as well. But unfortunately, for reasons I'm not in the mood to get into right now, and cannot change, I have to use BlueJ for certain projects in my class.

Don't get me wrong, I actually do like using BlueJ on simpler and smaller projects with it's simple interface, but one thing that really limits the speed I work at is having to hit "Compile", right-clicking the tester class, clicking "void main", and then hitting "Okay", EVERY single time I want to test the code. It's sluggish and takes infinitely longer than one button or a keyboard shortcut.

Is there any way, external modification or otherwise, that I could have a simpler method for compiling and running code in BlueJ? Even saving on one or two of these clicks would be greatly appreciated.